# Getting a object stored in a dict by a string key

Tags: python, python-2.7, object, dictionary

I successfully print a list of keys to the screen and then ask the user to type in a key name to get a specific object. This is the way i thought it worked:

```
print dict['bob']
```

and this would output the object stored with the 'bob' key however it does not. I'm assuming this problem arises because im storing objects and not strings or ints. If the name entered is a key it just prints the name again not the object and if it isn't a key it throws an error. The end result of this is to get a specified object so the user can view that objects attributes.

When the above statement is ran it just prints the key to the screen:

```
bob
```

printing my dictionary looks like this

```
{'Sal': <Employ_Class2.Employee object at 0x01EE38F0>, 'bob': <Emplo
y_Class2.Employee object at 0x01EE3930>, 'jack': <Employ_Class2.Employee o
bject at 0x01EE3990>, 'alexa': <Employ_Class2.Employee object at 0x01EE3870>,
'dave': <Employ_Class2.Employee object at 0x01EE3910>, 'sew
': <Employ_Class2.Employee object at 0x01EE3950>, 'tam': <Employ_Class2.Em
ployee object at 0x01EE39D0>}
```

Comment: what do you mean? what that statement returns?

Comment: What is in dict? How are you defining it? What do you get if you do `print dict`?

Comment: Then that is what you have stored in dict under the key `bob`. If you think you should have something different, you should show how you stored it in the first place.

Comment: I already said objects are in dict, and what is printed. Unclear about what you mean by how am i defining it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman that is not correct, because printing the dictionary to the screen shows that is not the case.

Comment: Can you please post what happens when you use `print dict`?

Comment: So why can't you post the result of doing `print dict`, which is what both Pankaj and I asked you to do?

Comment: I can, didnt know thats what you two were asking i will make and edit and post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're simply being misled by the fact that `print obj` prints the result of calling the object's `__str__` or `__unicode__` methods. So, the object in the dictionary under the key "bob", when converted to string, is simply "bob".

As others have said, if you simply want to print the attributes of the object under that key, use `dir`:

```
obj = dict['bob']
print dir(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view the names of the attributes of the object, use [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir).

If the dictionary contains the instances of the class you've created and you want to extract relevant information from those objects, you need to create in your class a function which does that and invoke it later.

Suppose you have an object of type `Product`, given that `Product` is the class you've created. You store multiple products in your dictionary. What do you want to get back? The name of the product? The name, the price and the description? Or maybe the class name? Python won't be able to figure out your intention, so it's up to you to either create a specific method which does what you want it to do, or use `__str__()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you wanted is `dir([object])` .

```
Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.
```

So according to the documentation you can have the attributes fro that object with `dir()`.

Hope this is what you have wanted..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are referring to object attributes you are defining in your class definition or the names you would find with `dir().` In either case, if your object class has a `__str__` or `__repr__` methods defined, those will be called when using print.  If you want a user to be able to view the names in the object space, just use `dir()`.  If you want them to access attributes and properties you set in the class definition, access them directly (or through whatever methods you created to do so:

```
class Test:
    attr = 'item'  # this is a class attribute
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Me'  # this will be an instance variable/property
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

d = {}   # example does not need a dict but using one to relate to posted question
d['item'] = Test()

print(d['item'])
```

results in `self.name` being printed to screen:

`dir(d['item'])` will instead print out all of the names in the object namespace, including methods and attributes.

To print your created attributes (`attr` and `self.name` above), then you can simply do:

```
print(d['item'].attr)
print(d['item'].name)
```

So, in that case, your users should just access the dict objects directly: `dict['bob'].attribute`

Hope that makes some sense.